# I can't access the admin panel in SilverStripe after the browser is reopened

Tags: browser, silverstripe

I have a strange problem with SilverStripe CMS... and browsers. Probably some stupid issue that I just can't fix.

I'm running SS on an Apache server, on my Linux box. Installation is fine, and I'm able to do everything. But when I close my browser, and then reopen it, the only thing I can see is the site itself. When I try to access the /admin page, I'm being asked for the password, and then I *should* be redirected to the CMS admin panel page. I am redirected, but all I can see is the "Loading..." message and the SS logo. Nothing more happens.

A simple procedure to reproduce it is as follows:

1. Install the SS.
2. Close the browser.
3. Reopen it.
4. Try to reach /admin.

What's really interesting, I checked the source code for the page (the CMS admin panel) I can't see in the browser: it seems to be fine. HTML is there. The page is not rendered properly, though.

I also checked my logs. Everything seems to be fine. No server errors (nothing like 404, or 5xx).

Before I close my browser (right after the SS installation), everything works fine. I'm able to access the admin panel. But after closing the browser, I can no longer access the admin panel - all I can see is the "Loading..." message and the SS logo. And it happens both locally and remotely.

I use both Chromium and FF, if it's of any importance. And they both behave the same.

---

Update:

The problem is solved. The solution was simple: just add the following line to the mysite/_config.php file.

Requirements::set_combined_files_enabled(false);

(Source: http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/14861#post296241)

Thanks for your remark, schellmax - how could I be so stupid and forget to check the console???

Comment: did you watch out for any js errors in the console?

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues - you need to set the proper permissions (777) on the `assets` folder. Otherwise some JS isn't properly combined and loaded in the admin interface.

Comment: now that you say it - i remember struggling with the same issue some time ago :)

Comment: Nope, `assets` is already 777. Doesn't the installer require those permissions to be 777 before installing SS?

Comment: Probably yes, but my general workflow is: install on the dev box, copy the code (git or whatever) to the live site + restore a DB dump from the dev box -> bad permissions.

Anyway - do you have a file `assets/_combinedfiles/leftandmain.js` (and probably some more)? That's the one, which always caused the error above for me, if it was missing...